# How Does A $\theta$ Angle Shift Affect the Wilsonian Effective Lagrangrian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, topological-field-theory

Say we have some quantum field theory which includes a gauge field, and some matter, and a topological $\theta$ term so that the Lagrangian reads
$$L=(stuff)+\frac{\theta}{64\pi^2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F^a_{\mu\nu}F^a_{\rho\sigma}$$

We know that the Lagrangian behaves as follows under the transformation $\theta\to\theta +a$
$$L\to L+\frac{a}{64\pi^2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F^a_{\mu\nu}F^a_{\rho\sigma}$$

If we now consider the Wilsonian Effective Lagrangian $L_{\Lambda}$, what can we say about how it transforms under a shift like $\theta\to\theta+a$? Can we say that it transforms the same way?

I ask this because this is what Weinberg assumes in section 29.3 of his Quantum Theory of Fields book, that it does indeed transform the same way. Specifically around equation 29.3.7.

Comment: The $\theta$ term is topological, whatever stuff you integrate out it still remains there, do you agree?

Comment: I could imagine there being high energy configurations with non-trivial winding number contributing to $L_{\Lambda}$.

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/472393/2451

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for how I can make this question more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Weinberg does not actually assume that the Wilsonian Effective Lagrangian transforms in the same way!

The statement he makes is that the transformation $\theta\to\theta+a$ with $a$ a specific number will *cancel* the transformation made by the anomaly. This is because these two transformations make equal but opposite contributions to the action *before* integrating out high energy modes.